# Unable to convert JKS keystore to Oracle Wallet using orapki

Tags: ssl-certificate, java, oracle, certificate-authority, keytool

I have generated jks keystore using keytool and using the jks keystore I have csr. The same csr I have sent to Signing authority.
The Signing authority have given the trusted certificates(root,intermediate and server) which I have imported using keytool command.
After importing I came to know about password policy restriction on Oracle Wallet(combination of alphanumeric,special characters and minimum length 8) and also that to convert jks to wallet, the passwords need to be same.
I have changed the keystore passwords(storepasswd,keypasswd) using following commands :

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias <Alias> -keystore KEYSTORE.jks
keytool -storepasswd -keystore KEYSTORE.jks
```

This I have done successfully. I am using `orapki` tool of `OHS` to convert jks keystore to oracle wallet using the following command:

```
orapki wallet jks_to_pkcs12 -wallet <WALLET> -keystore KEYSTORE.jks
```

and I am getting following exception

```
Exception : oracle.security.crypto.util.InvalidFormatException: Malformed attribute type
```

I have looked for this exception on the internet but have not found a good reference. Please provide some help on where the problem is or what error have I made?

Answer (score 0):

You need create a wallet first:

```
orapki wallet create -wallet oam.oracle.poc.wallet -pwd <pwd> -auto_login
```

Then do import again:

```
orapki wallet jks_to_pkcs12 -wallet oam.oracle.poc.wallet -pwd <pwd> -keystore <keystore.jks> -jkspwd <jks_pwd>
```

Remember, passwords of the keystore and key entries should be the same.